# How to automatically add a new row in Excel based on previous row data

Tags: excel, database, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Ok, I think this one will require a VBA code.

[Here is how my file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Nu6.png)

I'd like to automatically add a new row for every year so the file [to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRcHk.png).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty wordy but works... I know for sure there are more efficient ways of getting it done but here ya go

```
Sub sorter()

    Dim row As Long: row = 2
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim yearList As Variant
    Dim year As Variant
    Dim extra As Integer: extra = 0
    Dim numYears As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        Do While True
            yearList = Split(CStr(.Range("C" & row)), "|")
            numYears = UBound(yearList) - LBound(yearList) + 1

            If numYears > 1 Then
                For Each year In yearList
                    .Cells(row + extra, 1).Value = .Cells(row, 1).Value
                    .Cells(row + extra, 2).Value = .Cells(row, 2).Value
                    .Cells(row + extra, 3).Value = year

                    ' for cols D-F
                    .Cells(row + extra, 4).Value = .Cells(row, 4).Value
                    .Cells(row + extra, 5).Value = .Cells(row, 5).Value
                    .Cells(row + extra, 6).Value = .Cells(row, 6).Value

                    If extra = numYears - 1 Then Exit For

                    .Cells(row + extra + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                    extra = extra + 1
                Next year
                extra = 0
            End If
            row = row + 1
            If Len(CStr(.Range("A" & row))) = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @PeteT which line is yellow when you click "Debug"

Comment: @PeteT did you remember to change `"your sheet name"` to your actual worksheet name?

Comment: actually the worksheet contains 7 columns (A to F) with Year field in column C. How do I adjust the code in order to insert all the data (A to F)? Right now it inserts only A to C.

Comment: @PeteT Im in class now so I wont be able to edit the answer until later... but you can create a couple variables to hold the information for each cell each time you go to a new row

Comment: @PeteT  basically under the line “numYears = ...” just set 3 variables equal to one of each of the other columns data. Then add “.Cells(row + extra, 4).Value = yourvariableforcolumn4” and do that for the other 2 columns as well - sorry wrote this from mobile

Comment: @PeteT nice, comment back if you need any adjustments later on

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple
you wanna split the years if not already split

```
dim year_string() as string
rowint = 2
year_string = split([insert your cell address],"|")
for each year in year_string
    cells(rowint, 1).value2 = [insert your cell address]
    cells(rowint, 2).value2 = [insert your cell address]
    cells(rowint, 3).value2 = year
next year
```

Comment: should I insert your code as it is or do I need to change something?

Comment: you need to change "insert your cell address" to the three cell addresses, with an interating row number